# Does ''脅しじゃねえぞ'' mean ''not a threat''?

Tags: translation, definitions

I'm confused in this page from a manga the character says odoshi ja nee zo while hes having someone at gunpoint did he mean ''not a threat''?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think it means, "I'm not joking you".

This [link](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1293318752) mentions that 脅｛おど｝しじゃない means that it is not ***just*** a threat and that they really mean it.

Comment: So this use of 脅し could also be translated to "idle threat" or "bluff", i.e., "I'm not bluffing! (I *will* shoot you)"